# How to redirect error page when url contains special character?

Tags: apache, security, tomcat

I have a question in setting tomcat.

I want to show common error page when error occurs.
this is my client security needs.

But, if I access www.mydomain.com/..%5c, my common error page not works.

they show "HTTP ERROR 400 message".
I want to redirect my common error page..

this is my web.xml config.

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>400</error-code>
  <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
  <error-code>401</error-code>
  <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
  <error-code>403</error-code>
  <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
  <error-code>405</error-code>
  <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

And I add CATALINA_OPTS.
-Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.ALLOW_BACKSLASH=true
-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true

this option works in www.mydomain.com/%5c
but not working www.mydomain.com/..%5c

How can I redirect common error page when access www.mydomain.com/..%5c

Comment: What happens if you configure your `400` error response in the `ROOT` web application?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this program.

I think you can configure your filter in web.xml. In the filter you can implement the logic to process your request encoding and special characters, then redirect to the error page.

Configuration

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>name</filter-name>
      <filter-class>demoClass</filter-class>
  </filter>


  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>name</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Class to be implemented

```
    public class demoClass implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("----init----");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //TODO code 
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("----destory----");
    }
}
```

My English is poor